# didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor is not returning any characteristic of the HM-10 BLE

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am successfully able to discover the service using `didDiscoverServices`, from where I call the following function to discover the characteristics:

`peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service as CBService)`

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    if error != nil {
        print("[ERROR] Error discovering characteristics. \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    print("Found \(service.characteristics!.count) characteristics!: \(service.characteristics)")        
}
```

This prints: "Found 0 characteristics!: Optional([])"

I am not getting any characteristics from the BLE device. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally after connection, next step is to discover services. Now every service has its own characteristics. In you above call

```
peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service as CBService)
```

`service as CBService` may or may not have any characteristic. I suggest you to do one thing, check all the services your BLE device has and then discover characteristic for all services.

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
    guard let serviceError = error else {
        if let peripheralServices = peripheral.services {
            for service in peripheralServices {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service)
            }
        }
        return
    }

    print("Error in discovering Services. Error : \(serviceError.localizedDescription)")
}
```

May it will help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: I have already checked the services. I am able to discover and write to characteristics in android. My problem occurs in ios, that I am not able to retrieve any characteristic after successfully getting a service.

Comment: iOS BLE stack is better than google's android BLE stack. If you are able to read services and characteristics in android then try debugging and match the service CBUUID you are getting in android with iOS one.